# How to run CLI command "hangup request" with Java code

Tags: command-line, java, asterisk

I need run this with Java

> String command = "asterisk -rx \"hangup request ...\"" ;

but i got return i such command '"hangup'.

```
 asterisk -rx "hangup request ..."
```

okay when i type and run with CLI.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.exec(new String[]{"asterisk","-rx","hangup request ..."})
```

instead. `System.exec(String cmd)` does not honor any embedded quoting and splits the supplied string into pieces with "\s+" pattern.

Comment: thank you.
And one more question. How to many commands step by step?

Comment: I did not get you. What you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should not start enother copy of asterisk just for run hangup request.

Correct solution is use AMI interface to request hangup.